# How can I measure the times of my sorting algorithms in a single step?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am working on a exercise but I am stuck on one point

I want to measure the sorting times of 3 sorting algorithms (bubble,insertion and selection) using seven different arrays. I have tried multiple ways but I can't measure the sorting time of all three algorithms in a single step for all the arrays. My programme should:

- randomly fill the array with integers
- sort them
- measure the times
- print  the times

The results are always coming 0 millisecond but it can not be like that because I tried 1million integer array so, there is no possibility for coming 0 millisecond for it.Finally, I tried "for loop " for achieving the what will I do.

I should write the all my methods because you may find another errors in other methods.

```
public static void randomlyFillArray(int[] array, int a, int b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = randomInt(a, b);
    }
}

public static int randomInt(int a, int b) {
    return (int) ((b - a + 1) * Math.random() + a);

}

public static void SelectionSort(int[] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                // ... Exchange elements
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        temp = array[i];
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && array[j - 1] > temp) {
            array[j] = array[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}

public static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int temp;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - j; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // int[] array500 = new int[500];  //These are my arrays that I should do the process for //each one.
    // int[] array1000 = new int[1000];
    // int[] array5000 = new int[5000];
    // int[] array10000 = new int[10000];
    // int[] array50000 = new int[50000];
    // int[] array100000 = new int[100000];
    // int[] array500000 = new int[500000];
    // int[] array1000000 = new int[1000000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        int[] array = new int[500];
        if (i == 1) {
            randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);
            SelectionSort(array);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long total = 0;

            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
            SelectionSort(array);
            System.out.println("SelectionSort for 500 integer :  "
                    + elapsedTime);

        } else if (i == 2) {
            randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);
            insertionSort(array);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long total = 0;

            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
            insertionSort(array);
            System.out.println("InsertionSort for 500 integer :  "
                    + elapsedTime);
        } else if (i == 3) {
            randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);
            bubbleSort(array);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long total = 0;

            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
            bubbleSort(array);

            System.out.println("BubbleSort for 500 integer :  "
                    + elapsedTime);

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you for your all advices stackoverflow family.

Sincerely.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to sort 1 million integers in less than a millisecond. Try system.nanoTime() instead

Comment: You take the starting time after sorting, maybe you should start measuring before you sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your timing blocks look like this:

```
randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);
SelectionSort(array);
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long total = 0;
long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
SelectionSort(array);
System.out.println("SelectionSort for 500 integer :  " + elapsedTime);
```

You sort, *then* take the start time, then immediately take the end time, *then* sort again, then print the times. You have to take the end time *after* the sort. If you have a reason for sorting twice ('warming up' the JVM?), make sure that you re-randomize the array before you do the timed sort. An algorithm's performance for sorting an already sorted array might be much different.

```
randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long total = 0;  // this thing is never used...
SelectionSort(array); // move this line between start time and end time!
long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
System.out.println("SelectionSort for 500 integer :  " + elapsedTime);
```

Also, much of that code is the same for each of those sorts. You can move those parts out of the `if/else` blocks and into the loop, making the whole code more compact and easier to maintain. Also, you can create another loop around that one for the different array sizes.

```
for (int num : new int[] {500, 1000, 5000, ...}) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        String sort = null;
        int[] array = new int[num];
        randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (i == 1) {
            sort = "SelectionSort";
            SelectionSort(array);
        } else if (i == ...) {
            // analogeous for other sorts
        }
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(sort + " for " + num + " integers: " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly,thank you for your answer.I made up some changes on my code but I didn't understand the last part of your answer because if I initialize the num = 500 then my array has 500 integers but this will be run only for 500 integers.How can we make it up for all different arrays ? Because,I want to write a method for this process and I want to run it for all arrays.This looks like very complicated and simple.

Comment: @mertha You can create another loop around that first one, iterating over the different array sizes. See my edit.

Comment: I don't understand again because of my Java level.Nevertheless,I should write what I understand from your comment.

I think,I will create another "for loop" in the if(i==1) part for providing the process of all arrays.Then i will erase the int num and initialize the one array then I will call like timeSort(my method name)(array10000); in the main method.But,I don't think I can do it.

Comment: oh,sorry for the previous comment tobias,I see it now .Ok,I will try it then write the result here.Thank you again.

Comment: I tried you advice and I reached what I want to do .Dankeschön Tobias !

Answer (score 2):

creating microbenchmarks can be tricky, because the JIT compiles frequently used code, which takes some time of its own...

so my approach is usually like this:

```
public void measureSorting(int[] array) {
    // this should be sufficiently large
    long start, end;
    randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);

    // warm up JIT - execute without measuring
    SelectionSort(array);
    randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);

    // stop the time
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SelectionSort(array);
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.printf("SelectionSort for %d integer :  %d milliseconds", array.length, end-start);

    // repeat for other algorithms
}
```

If you are using Java8, you can even create something like this:

```
public static void measureSorting(int[] array, Consumer<int[]> sortingFunction) {
    // this should be sufficiently large
    long start, end;
    randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);

    // warm up JIT - execute without measuring
    sortingFunction.accept(array);
    randomlyFillArray(array, 1, 1000);

    // stop the time
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    sortingFunction.accept(array);
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // repeat for other algorithms

    System.out.printf("%s for %d integer :  %d milliseconds", sortingFunction, array.length, end-start);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // assuming the enclosing class is Sorter
    measureSorting(new int[500], Sorter::SelectionSort);
    measureSorting(new int[500], Sorter::insertionSort);
    measureSorting(new int[500], Sorter::bubbleSort);
}
```

Comment: Firstly,thank you for your answer Max.I tried your changes on my code in eclipse but I didn't understand how to make them for all arrays.Because,it will only work for 10000 integer arrays like this way.But how can we process it for all arrays ? Because I will write a method for this like ;

`public static void sortTime(int [] array){


:
:
:
:    These punctiations  are "for loops"
:
:
:
:
:


}


Then my main method :

public static void main(String [] args){


sortTime(array500);
sortTime(array1000);
sortTime(array5000);
sortTime(array10000);
.
.
.



and the other arrays

}
`

Comment: Thank you for your edit Max,I will try it and write the result here.Thank you for your help again.

Comment: Thank you for your help Max.I tried also your advice then I reached what I want to do.Dankeschön Max !